# Accessing data from DB according to drop down selection using Rails 3

Tags: ruby, drop-down-menu, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have one doubt.I have a form which has two drop down field.when user will select option from first drop down list,accordingly all required value will fetch from db and set in second drop down list.Check my below code.

> views/payments/payment.html.erb:

```
<div class="tbpaddingdiv2">
        <%= form_for :payment,:url => {:action => "check_type" },remote: true do |f| %>
        <div class="totalaligndiv">
          <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Type :</div></span>
          <%= f.select(:s_catagory,options_for_select([['Wood','Wood'],['Puja Samagree','Puja Samagree'],['Sweeper','Sweeper'],['Photo Grapher','Photo Grapher'],['Burning Assistant','Burning Assistant']],selected: "Type"),{},{:class => 'form-control'},{:onchange => ''}) %>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Select Vendor :</div></span>
            <select class="form-control">
                <option selected>Selected Vendor</option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
            </select> 
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
          <div class="tbpaddingdiv1 text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
```

> controller/payments_controller.rb:

```
 class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
        def payment
            @payment=Vendor.new
        end
        def check_type
           @vendor=Vendor.find_by_s_catagory(params[:s_catagory])
       end
    end
```

Check my view page.There are two drop down menu.I can not complete this.First user will select value from first drop down menu.As soon as value will selected the data base search operation will start and all required value will fetched.The retrieved value will set in second drop down list.After that submit button will be clicked for other purpose.I am using Rails version 3.2.19.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

change your view, assign some class to vendor select div like:

```
.vendor_partial
   = render partial: "select_vendors"
```

on select of `s_catagory` you will send ajax request to `check_type` and render returned `@vendor` in div for selected vendors,
in your `check_type.js.haml` file:

```
(".vendor_partial").html("#{escape_javascript(render partial: "select_vendors")}")
```

and `_select_vendors.html.haml` :

```
= collection_select(:vendor, :id, (@vendor.nil? ? [] : @vendor), :id, :vendor_name, prompt: "Select vendor")
```

Comment: @ Anuja :I can not understand your last line of your code.

Comment: @satya its for displaying vendor select list, refer this http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select